# Connecting to TFS 2010 server and MS Project 2007 editions - how does it work?

Tags: team-foundation-server, microsoft-project

I'm wondering if I can connect to TFS 2010 with my Microsoft Project 2007 Standard Edition or do I have to possess at least Professional edition? Do anybody knows that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question is very simple. Yes I/You can connect to TFS using standard edition of MS Project. Below is a note about differences between both editions:

Here’s Microsoft’s explanation:

1. Office Project Standard 2007 is the latest version of the desktop project management program. As a stand-alone product, Office Project Standard 2007 helps project managers, business managers, and planners to manage and plan projects independently with familiar, easy-to-use tools. Office Project Standard 2007 is not designed to exchange data with Office Project Server 2007.
2. Office Project Professional 2007 is the desktop client that is also used to connect with Office Project Server 2007 as part of the Office EPM Solution. Office Project Professional 2007 offers all the tools found in Office Project Standard 2007, and when used with Office Project Server 2007, it also provides powerful EPM capabilities such as collaboration, management of shared resources, portfolio management, and reporting across projects and programs run by different project managers.